# How to remove a channel (pypi.org) from Conda

Tags: python, conda, pypi

I am making a facial recognition program in Python with Conda but it gives an error as

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed


UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
channel name: None
channel url: https://pypi.org
error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

Why am I seeing this and how do I resolve it?

Comment: You seem to be having a problem adding a package to conda.  Please provide the details of the conda command being executed when error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Channels can be edited by either manually editing the user-level configuration file (find it with `conda config --show-sources`, as indicated in the error) or by using the `conda config` command, e.g.,

```
conda config --remove channels 'https://pypi.org'
```

It may be worth first checking `conda config --show channels` first, to make sure that is exactly the string that needs to be removed.

It remains unclear to me why one would have such a channel added in the first place.